# How to insert value from stored procedure to variable in function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns a value (ex: `GetData`)

How can I declare a variable in another function to get this value?

Something like this

```
Create Function Test
Return Int
Begin
    Declare @data My_Data_Type
    Declare @count int
    SET @data = exec GetData
    Select @count = count(*)
    From @data

    Return @count
End
```

Please help me !!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your stored procedure returns table then do

```
declare @data as table(col1 int, col2 varchar(50))

insert into @data exec GetData

Select @count = count(*) from @data
```

If you want to return scalar valus e.g. int, varchar, use OUTPUT parameter

```
CREATE PROC GetData
(
   @retVal int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
     SET @retVal = 123

     Return 0
END
```

Then retrieve it this way

```
 declare @data int
 EXEC GetData @data OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Using a Stored Procedure with Output Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> A SQL Server stored procedure that you can call is one that returns
>   one or more OUT parameters, which are parameters that the stored
>   procedure uses to return data back to the calling application.

Also [Returning Data by Using OUTPUT Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> If you specify the OUTPUT keyword for a parameter in the procedure
>   definition, the stored procedure can return the current value of the
>   parameter to the calling program when the stored procedure exits. To
>   save the value of the parameter in a variable that can be used in the
>   calling program, the calling program must use the OUTPUT keyword when
>   executing the stored procedure.